# Always Invalid username with/without bad words

Tags: php, passwords

I am tryiny to write code that denies any username that contains bad words.
No matter what I do - I get "Invalid username."

```
$f = @fopen("censor.txt", "r");

$bw = fread($f, filesize("censor.txt"));
$banned_words = explode("\n", $bw);

function teststringforbadwords($wantusername, $banned_words)
{
    foreach ($banned_words as $banned_word) {
        if (stristr($wantusername, $banned_word)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}

if (!teststringforbadwords($wantusername, $banned_words)) {
    echo 'string is clean';
} else {
    echo('string contains banned words');
    $message = "Invalid username.";
}

@fclose($f);
```

I am currently learning php and have tried everything I can think of to get it to work - help!

Comment: what values `$banned_words` and `$wantusername` have? also  instead of `foreach` loop you need only `if(in_array($wantusername,$banned_words)) {return false;}else{return true;}`

Comment: @A-2-A or even shorter, `return !in_array($wantusername, $banned_words);`

Comment: FYI, `fread()` followed by `explode)` is equivalent to `file()`.

Comment: @A-2-A `in_array` is case-sensitive.

Comment: @A-2-A `in_array` looks for exact matches, `stristr` matches anywhere in the haystack.

Comment: I assume a case that `sexy-man` will never equals to `sex` or `sexy`. Sorry i have to add my assumption too.

Comment: @A-2-A if `sex` is banned, `sexy-man` is banned by `stristr `

Comment: according to me it is not correct, but may be OP want it to ban also.

Comment: @A-2-A I don't understand. OP say “username **that contains**”

Comment: hey i am not telling you are wrong. I just put my assumption. Its ok, don't be panic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function works fine, but you call it in not correct way, because the function return `False` if a bad word if matched:

```
if( teststringforbadwords( $wantusername, $banned_words ) )
{
    echo 'string is clean';
}
else
{
    echo('string contains banned words');
    $message = "Invalid username.";
}
```

Otherwise, if you want maintain coherence with function name, you have to invert `True` and `False` returns inside function.

Comment: Thanks, that worked once I decided not to use @fopen, but to instead declare the array of banned_words in file.     Ex.$banned_words = array("*",.........);

Comment: @dewey this is strange. I have tested your script even with `fopen` and it works fro me... Are you sure that there are not spaces before/after words and your endline char is lf (`\n`)?

Comment: it is strange, but I must have done something wrong - when I retyped it, it works perfectly.  May have had spaces.  Thanks